# How can I disable or control Visual Studio 2010 tab groups?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I seem to have accidentally created Visual Studio 2010 tab groups which means that some documents I open appear in a new vertical tab group. How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Have you tried "Window" -> "Reset window layout"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have create two groups, allowing two documents open side by side you can just drag tabs from one group to the other (or use the tab's context menu).

When the last tab is closed or moved to another group the whole group will close.

Comment: That's how I'd assumed it would work, but it seems that some documents are remembering that they used to be in a different tab group and when I re-open them they open in a separate tab group.

Comment: @tjrobinson: Delete the (hidden) solution.suo file before re-opening the solution. This saves per solution settings (files open, breakpoints, debug settings, ...) and would be the place such information is stored.

Comment: Deleting the .suo file worked, that should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Click mouse right button on one of the tab group bar
2. Select `Move all to next tab group`